# Make observables used in computed value watched even if not used in last computation

Tags: javascript, mobx

I'm just wondering, if there's an idiomatic approach to make observables used in computed value watched even if not used in last computation.

Let's say I have this code:

```
@observable array = [];

@computed get arrayLength(){
  if (condition) return true;
  return this.array.length;
}
```

If the codition is true, computed value will just auto return true, and won't make this.array watched.
So if array changes in the future, arrayLength won't get re-computed.

One way I was using is just referencing observables.
The code above can work if I change it this way

```
@computed get arrayLength(){
  const array = this.array;
  if (condition) return true;
  return array.length;
}
```

Is there any other good approach to this? Or is it just generally a bad idea to write a computed value that in some cases dependend on an observable, and in some cases don't?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: If you make `condition` observable as well, it will resolve itself, no?

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/613. In short? Why should it recomputate if `condition` is true, it won't affect the outcome of the computation...